# Excel's max function returning wrong value when using vlookup

Tags: excel, max, vlookup

In `Microsoft Excel 2011 (OSX)`, I am using the `MAX` function to obtain the largest value between two cells. The values in these two cells are obtained from other worksheet using `VLOOKUP`.

This is working fine in most of the rows, except in a couple of situations where the output of the `MAX` function is the lowest number. If I replace the `VLOOKUP` function by numbers, it works as expected.

The `VLOOKUP` formula that I am using is: `=VLOOKUP(A43;WorkSheet!$A$6:$C$123;3;FALSE)` and the `MAX` formula is simply `=MAX(E43,F43)`. All cells are formated as Number.

Any suggestions on how to debug this? What might be causing this behavior?

Comment: Hum...maybe vlookup is not returning a number and then ignored by max?

Comment: Providing sample data and formula itself would be useful. There is no way to see how "couple of situations" are different from "in most of the rows" from your question.

Comment: MAX() will provide incorrect results if one or more of its inputs are **Text** rather than number(s)

Comment: I added some more information to the question. Thanks.

Comment: If the VLOOKUP always returns "numbers" then try adding +0 to the end to convert text-formatted numbers to "true" numbers - then your MAX function should work OK, i.e. `=VLOOKUP(A43;WorkSheet!$A$6:$C$123;3;FALSE)+0`

Comment: @barryhoudini Adding `+0` worked! This is quite scary since the problem was visible in only a couple of rows (among dozens). How can I avoid similar situations?

Comment: If the values returned by VLOOKUP are text formatted then the source data in `WorkSheet!$C$6:$C$123` must also be in that format (at least some of those are formatted as text). Where does that data come from? If it's fixed I suggest running "text to columns" on that data - select that range then use Data > Text to Columns > Finish - that should convert "text numbers" to real numbers

Comment: @barryhoudini How do I accept your comment (suggesting `+0`) as the correct answer? I checked and all cells, including those referenced by `VLOOKUP`, are formatted as Number. So I don't understand where this problem comes from. Thanks anyway.

Comment: How did you check? Excel allows you to change the format to number.....but it may still **NOT** be a number - to check definitively use ISNUMBER function, e.g. `=ISNUMBER(Worksheet!C6)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding `+0` to the end of the `VLOOKUP()` function as suggested by Barry Houdini in the comments solved my problem.